# pig regex to extract data between tags

Tags: regex, apache-pig

My text file (input):

```
City,Description
Chicago,One day car rental is <b>$90</b>
Dallas,One day car rental is <b>$65</b>
```

Output needed:

```
City   Costofrental
Chicago, $90
Dallas,  $65
```

I am using `regex` extract to get the `cost ($)` details but not getting desired output. New to `regex` so please let me know what am i missing? TIA

```
A = LOAD '/user/Testfile.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS(a1:chararray,a8:chararray); 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE a1,REGEX_EXTRACT(a8, '/<b>([0-9]*)</b>/',1);
dump B;
```

Comment: You may just need to properly escape your `/` in `</b>` -- `<\/b>`.

Comment: thanks Sam & stribizhev. @stribizhev- unfortunately I am still getting the window popup asking for scripts variable input.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add escaped `\$` to your regex (and escape closing `</b>` tag):

```
'/<b>(\$[0-9]*)<\/b>/'
```

Comment: thanks. window popsup asking for script variables
run testrial script?
script variables
[0 =

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Apache Pig, only with regexes.

Comment: np. appreciate ur help!